# Colour shift when viewing render outside of blender

Tags: rendering, image, color-management

So this is what occurs the left is original right is when its saved [image]

knowing tiff saves it raw, I did it and was able to open it in Photoshop the same way(correct) it was in blender but just like blender when I tried to save it in Photoshop the colour keeps changing

Comment: If the file is reopened in blender or photoshop the rendered jpeg or png it comes back with the correct colour, tried 16,8 colour depth as well with different compression's

Comment: Did you check the color management settings in the scene tab to check if you are using the same color space in photoshop and blender?

Comment: Just curious, could this be an illusion? The one in Blender always has dark grey around it, while many other applications have lighter menus. Your brain might trick you into thinking there was a difference. Click and hold on a specific place on the image in Blender and see the exact color values on the bottom of the screen, and compare with when it is exported.

Comment: check your screen's display profile (in control panel, diplay, resolution -> advanced parameters - color management tab). using specific profile can lead to differences between windows/blender/photoshop colors.

Answer (score 11):

Blender saves to different formats using different techniques and curving according to some file based assumptions. TIFFs do not save "raw" by default, nor does the term "raw" have any real meaning here. Some examples file formats may have on output include:

- Saving to a JPEG or TIFF at 8 bits per channel will apply a nonlinear sRGB curve to the data, and may change the internal float format to the respective format's storage type.
- Saving to an EXR will transfer the internal reference space buffers unchanged which, by nature of EXR, is a linearized float scene referred format.

From what I can deduce from your screenshot(?) it appears that a subtle shifting is happening in the intensity along the trunk. This suggests that the right image is being color managed for your display from within Photoshop.

Blender *does not* use ICCs for color management, nor is the display corrected by default[1]. Further, it will *not* tag images with ICC profile information when saving. This means that the software will make a guess as to what reference space the image is in when it is loaded.

If I had to speculate, I would guess that the image viewer on the right is color correcting the assumed sRGB image format you have loaded. This effectively takes the theoretical sRGB values output from Blender and attempts to emulate the correct sRGB values based on a profile of your display. It may also have to do with an incorrect reference space being set from within your image viewer.

So without further information, it would be impossible to diagnose what is happening with absolute certainty. That said, if you open the color management settings in Photoshop, you will likely find a display correction profile in place there, or an incorrect working reference space ICC profile. In the case of the former, you can disable the display profile and see the raw dump to the screen as Blender rendered it. In the case of the latter, there are sadly many sRGB ICC profiles out there that are not identical to each other, and some are even outright incorrect[2].

Hope this helps you make a little progress into figuring out the issue.

---

1. Blender *can* be augmented to display color critical and accurate results, hardware depending. This involves profiling one's display, converting the resulting profile into a 3D LUT, and inserting it into the OpenColorIO configuration set.
2. The sRGB.icm ICC file included with the Argyll color management system is accurate and should deliver proper output.

Comment: Great answer Troy, I'd love to read more about point 1 regarding the setup of Blender to display colour accurate output. Maybe a blog post somewhere? Cheers.

Comment: @ToddMcIntosh Perhaps if someone asks the question at some point I'll do my best to provide an answer.

Comment: Okay, have at it! http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31068/how-can-blender-be-augmented-to-display-color-critical-and-accurate-results