# Linear gradient wrong

Tags: texturing, materials, color

I am comparing (for an entire day now) two .blend files (one mine and one from [blender wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Tutorials/Textures/Maps/Creating_a_Heightmap_from_a_Plane)), why linear gradient texture settings that have exact settings aren't the same (or I'm just unable to spot the difference).

The problems is that gradient from my file is much whiter (lower gradient on an image below), causing incorrect height map generation.

Can someone please help solve this mystery for me.

[Link to both Blender files.](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/scjf9hj709ja7rj/AAATujyw_4Usx-u8rOPXyOvVa?dl=0)

[image: different gradients]
*Not the nicest crop but the difference should be clearly visible.*

**EDIT:** I'm using latest Blender (2.76b), while original.blend file was probably created using 2.4x.

Comment: related?: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40253/cycles-gradient-texture-node-linear-is-not-linear

Comment: I've seen it, checked it, but it isn't it. There aren't any nodes involved nor Cycles either.

Comment: It appears to work better if you apply the multires modifier and center the origin, but this probably isn't an acceptable workaround. Note that the *display device* settings in *Scene > Color Management* differ between the two .blends, this causes the gradients to differ in the UI

Comment: > see: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ee9Lw.gif

Comment: I was performing my tests with mutlires modifier applied (I noticed that it doesn't work with modifier, but it would be nice though). Didn't know about _Scene -> Color Management_, works now. Thanks to both gandalf3 and Leon95!