# how does the color ramp interpolation work?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, node-editor

how does the interpolation of the color ramp node in cycle affect the behaviour of the color ramp. During modelling the interpolation meant the shape of the curve, but while using node it must be something different........... How would this affect the values physically and technically(i.e. how would it carry out internally and how would blender interpret the input value of the color ramp)?

Comment: It is actually based on a curve, the steepness of the curve showing how quickly the color changes, etc. Each of the points can be seen as control points on a 2D curve, with the `value` showing height, and position showing side-to-side positioning.

Comment: Is there any way to visualize this in the real time viewport?

Comment: I have an idea of how to visualize it

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An easy way to visualize this is to add a plane with a displacement modifier with a *Blend* texture and *Colors > Ramp* selected. Start by adding and subdividing a plane:

[image: The plane]

You can add a subdivision-surface modifier as well for added detail. Now add a *Displace* modifier, and click `New` to make a new texture. Go to the texture panel and select *Blend*:

[image: Blend Texture]

Now you can edit the waypoints and the interpolation types as you wish and view their results in real time. This will really help you see how the colors are mixed using a color-ramp.

---

**Constant:**

[image: Constant]

**B-Spline:**

[image: B-Spline]

**Linear:**

[image: Linear]

**Cardinal:**

[image: Cardinal]

**Ease:**

[image: Ease]

**To visualize Cycles**

Add a plane, unwrap it and add a gradient texture to an emission shader:

**LINEAR**

[image]

**QUADRATIC**

[image]

**Easing**

[image]

**Diagonal**

[image]

**Spherical**

[image]

**Quadratic Sphere**

[image]

**Radial**

[image]

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40253/cycles-gradient-texture-node-linear-is-not-linear

Comment: what is exactly the difference between linear and cardinal ? I cannot see much of a difference and still Sardi Pax is using cardinal instead of linear in one of his tutorials

Comment: There is a slight amount of easing. Do not use cardinal interpolation for height maps or other depth data