# Why does the color on the object not match the color set in the material?

Tags: shaders, color

[image]

When I use shader in blender. I find it's hard to set a color to object. Just like the picture shows, the output color will change.

Is there something worry in my setting?
Or. What should I do?

Comment: Maybe check this out? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48943/color-codes-in-image-do-not-match-the-material and this for accurate colour rendering (as commented in the above post) https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31068/how-can-blender-be-augmented-to-display-color-critical-and-accurate-results

Comment: Have you set the colormanagement to *raw*?

Comment: @ThunderBolt832 Thanks!!! I find the reason: Scene: Color Management: View Transform. this val should set to "Standard", not the default val: "Filmic"

Comment: @Leander  You are right! the reason is Color Management. Thanks!!!

Comment: It may have to do with lights.