# Colors from imported image in compositor aren't displaying correctly

Tags: compositing-nodes, color-management, color

When importing images for use as a starting image in blenders compositor the colors do not display correctly.
I tried different ways to fix this issue but can't find a solution.

My guess would be that it's a gamma issue but I can't be 100% sure.

I may be colorblind but can still notice that this isn't right. :)

Any suggestions?

Import image node:

[image]

Original image:
[image]

Imported/Saved image:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the color space to sRGB in the image node (or the UV/Image editor) and also enable **view as render**. In the color management section set the Display device and Render View to sRGB

[image]

Comment: read also: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31068/how-can-blender-be-augmented-to-display-color-critical-and-accurate-results and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28284/colour-shift-when-viewing-render-outside-of-blender/29006#29006