# Texture after modeling is very light? Ambient occlusion with photoshop

Tags: uv, texture-baking, texture-painting

I'm trying to reproduce a model from a youtube tutorial. I'm currently trying to texture my model using photoshop. I've unwrapped my model successfully, but now when I paint the UV islands and load the image into blender, my textures/colors don't have the desired look, and I'm unsure why. It appears that they are very light. I believe it has something to do with how I baked my ambient occlusion image?

Here's the ambient occlusion image with all the layers in photoshop in the **tutorial**
[image]

Here's what **mine** looks like in photoshop
[image]

Here's his model textured in blender in the **tutorial**
[image]

Here's **my** model texture in blender
[image]

I set the sampling in "world" to 20 like he did.
This happens for every color. I tried just straight black and it turned pretty light gray.

Can anyone help?

Comment: make sure that you are using the correct colorspace for your output, and that that colorspace is being correctly interpreted in photoshop and blender. Read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28284/colour-shift-when-viewing-render-outside-of-blender/29006#29006 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28284/colour-shift-when-viewing-render-outside-of-blender/29006#29006 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/51156/1853

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it! I had to change the blend mode on both my AO layer and my UV layer to "Multiply" in photoshop. I had only changed my AO layer to multiply, but the UV layer needed it as well.

[image]

Comment: Just turn of Layer 0. It's a UV image :)