# Rendered View port and PNG output color difference

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, 3d-view, color, color-management

I am performing a render on a scene through the viewport using f12 option and saving the rendered image but when viewing the two images side by side I've noticed that the colors are much sharper in the view port with higher contrast. This is especially noticeable on red and green objects.

I am using the default color management options and sRGB color space. 
Is this difference in color caused by some interpolation when converting the rendered view port image to a png format?

I am on Linux Ubuntu 16.04 and opening the image on Gnome Image viewer.

Comment: How are you comparing the images?

Comment: Possibly related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51154/colors-from-imported-image-in-compositor-arent-displaying-correctly/51156#51156

Comment: Not enough information. Platform and image viewer required here.

Comment: EyeOfGnome shows a color-corrected image according to the default system color profile; I don't think what you see within Blender undergoes the same process

Comment: I have encountered this as well. I would still need to further investigate, so this is merely an assumption: I found Blender doesn't assign color sync profiles to the png files that you save. You could use Gimp to assign the sRGB profile manually and try again. Also, the color profile of your display should match that.

Comment: Again, this question requires more information. Everything is speculation until we know what platform the individual is on and the image viewer in question to start. This is very likely a system colour management issue unrelated to Blender.