# Color tab Weirdness

Tags: color-management

My white color tab is faintly green. The Hex is ffffff.  Material created is white in the viewport.  It doesn't affect the output white objects are still white. It doesn't make sense to color correct the monitor. What gives?

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31068/how-can-blender-be-augmented-to-display-color-critical-and-accurate-results

Comment: This strongly sounds like you are using a different viewer or have some degree of operating system colour management employed, or your display is potentially off. Not enough information to even begin to answer the question.

Comment: Would [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/105077/2217) by any chance be the answer to this question? If so you could of posted an answer here, and not asked a new question as an answer.