# Saved still image doesn't really look like the one rendered

Tags: rendering

Did anybody notice when you render something and want to save the still image as a png file, or other file, the save doesn't really look like the rendered image in blender. I tried probably all the combinations with RGB, RGBA, 8,16 bits no luck. Subtle nuances of texture and color are not the same as the rendered view in blender both from Eevee and Cycles. Why is that? Does anybody know any trick that will save the same image without any noticeable loss of colors or texture highlights? Please let me know, thank you.

---

For clarification purposes. Rendered still images saved in Blender, any picture format, and viewed in Windows Photo Gallery have a slight difference in color and texturing. This is due to the inability of the Windows app to recreate exactly the original image. It will not happen when viewing with a professional software like Adobe Photosop, Paintshop Pro, Gimp, Affinity and so on.

Comment: Please show an example of the image in preview and the rendered result. Also what sofware are you using to preview? If the image viewer you are using is using a different color space that might cause trouble. Load the images back to blender to compare. [Add images to your post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help us understand your scene and settings.

Comment: It's a project I'm working on right now and unfortunately I can't share pictures of it until is completely out. I hope you understand that. Let me try what you mentioned above and I will get back to you.

Comment: Let me clarify this for you. When I send the picture out for reviewing people open it Windows Photo Gallery and not Adobe Photoshop, Paintshop Pro etc, like the usual viewing. I need the picture to look the same in default Windows Viewer app.

Comment: The question stands: are the images different when loaded back in blender?

Comment: read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28284/colour-shift-when-viewing-render-outside-of-blender and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98279/color-difference-in-saved-images-vs-render-view

Comment: The picture is the same when loaded back in Blender. How do I get it to look just like in Blender in Windows Photo Gallery?

Comment: It means "photo gallery" is interpreting the image wrong... teach others to use a proper app to review...