# Rendered transparent RGBA png looks different when imported to Adobe

Tags: rendering, export, transparency

On the left hand of the image is a screen shot from my render in Blender. On the right hand is a screen shot of the same image when imported to After Effects. In AE the chin and throat disappears and the neck shines trough. The same happens when testing the image in Photoshop. I have used cycles.

Best

Staffan[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. What Bit Depth are you using ? and how are you saving the image?

Comment: Thanks! Now I notice that I am using color depth 8 instead of 16. That might be the problem. I am not sure I understand your other question though. I use render image.

Comment: Nope, the color depth did not help.

Comment: There's a difference in how the hair looks too. Blender might be rendering the transparency differently.

Comment: Is it possible that you have additional objects that aren't visible in the viewport but are being exported?  Also, might there be an issue with backface culling?

Comment: No additional objects. I have disabled them in the render. Backfaced culling sounded like a good idea. However I tried ticking backeface culling box in Materials - Viewport display - Settings. It didn't help.

Comment: @StaffanWesterlund I mean something like [THIS](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98279/color-difference-in-saved-images-vs-render-view) way to save an image

Answer (score 1):

I solved it! It was a very stupid and simple mistake. When I looked closely in the render viewport I could see that the chin was actually transparent. It could be seen more clearly though when moved to another background layer. The problem was I had a transparent BSDF in my shader. After disconnecting it, everything looks fine.

Thanks for you efforts trying to help me!