# Render Image Off-Color From Original Render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, export, color

I've been having some trouble with rendering my image. When I render the image in blender, then it looks fine, but when I save it as a file to my computer, then it gets somewhat pale, and doesn't look like I want it to. I've tried using different image opening programs, but its the same thing for all of them. Here's what a quick render I did looked like after I saved it:
[image]

And here's a screenshot of the image as it looked in blender after I rendered it:
[image]
What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Related: [Colour shift when viewing render outside of blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/29006/1853) and [How can Blender be augmented to display color critical and accurate results?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31068/how-can-blender-be-augmented-to-display-color-critical-and-accurate-results)

Comment: It could be that your saving it in a way that compresses the colors? Wierd

Comment: File format that you are saving to?