# Can I use my 3D Luts with Flimic?

Tags: color, color-management, filmic-blender

I found this documentation → [How can Blender be augmented to display color critical and accurate results?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31068/how-can-blender-be-augmented-to-display-color-critical-and-accurate-results)

However, this is outdated and does not work now.

How can I use the 3D Luts extracted from the calibration profile with Flimic in 2.83?

Comment: So, is there any way to use my calibrated display profile with Flimic's dynamic range?
I haven't really understood this topic yet, so please bear with me.
What I want is to see in Blender the same color as Photoshop with ICC profile.

Comment: Yeah, you're right but I couldn't add a comment due to lack of points.
Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can add your color LUTs at the end of the existing color transforms chain to have a more accurate display.

You can add the color profile LUT to the folder where all of the other LUTs for blender are, or edit the config.ocio to look for the luts in an aditional folder.

Next, you need to create new definitions or stanzas in the config.ocio  file based on the existing ones and concatenate the LUTs at the end of the color transform chain.

Use the color corrected view transforms to work in blender, but know that you need disable them for the final output, as you don't want to bake your monitor's curves into the file.

Here's an example of an added lut the *medium contrast Look* to make things look blueish

Note the name change and how a lut called *testlut* is added at the end of the transforms chain.

```
- !<Look>
name: Medium Low Contrast BLueTest
process_space: Filmic Log
transform: !<GroupTransform>
    children:
        - !<FileTransform> {src: filmic_to_0-60_1-04.spi1d, interpolation: linear}
        - !<FileTransform> {src: filmic_to_0-70_1-03.spi1d, interpolation: linear, direction: inverse}
        - !<FileTransform> {src: testlut.cube, interpolation: linear}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. when I use this method, it seems that the dynamic range is broken, and can't control exposure because I can't use Flimic. Can't color calibrate with my LUT while using Flimic?

Comment: Yes, you can use filmic,  but you just got to be careful at what point you apply the LUT transform. It should be at the very end of the chain. Once the data has been converted to display referred. Not before.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65948/how-to-make-3d-luts-and-use-them-in-blender/66600#66600

Comment: Thank you very much! You gave me hope. I'll go over those articles more.
It would be nice if Blender just works like Photoshop. As an artist with no knowledge, it is difficult to understand this.

Comment: Oh no! I would not like blender to behave like photoshop when it comes to color! On the other hand if you take a bit of time to learn about color, then you will gain control on how your images are viewed and reproduced correctly. A good place to start that journey is @troy_s [Hitchheiker's Guide to Digital Color](https://hg2dc.com/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It seems to be a long journey.  I just wanted to match the colors, but the cost is high.

Comment: See edited answer.

Comment: Wow!!!! It works perfectly! You are the best, thank you soooooo much!!!!!

Comment: Susu has outlined most of the important aspects. Always remember that a LUT is like a formula, in discretized form. That means that any LUT is specifically designed for one input state, and will deliver to one output state. Both must be known! Use decent tools and you should be fine. Most contemporary displays are pretty decent, so much so that the degree of correction might be negligible. Be careful when manually characterizing displays; one small mistake can bog things up worse than not doing anything.

Comment: I have always been grateful for your contribution. Thanks a million, Troy!