# How to create a custom colour management profile

Tags: python, rendering, scripting, add-on, color-management

I am interested in creating a custom colour management profile. How you can get an image that looks very different depending if you use log or film or false colour, except I want to try and create a toon profile. One that will basically take the millions of colours normally rendered and round them to the nearest colour available of say a couple hundred.

Yes I know this is possible through shaders, but this requires manual tweaking of every material for every scene and every light. For a small project sure, but not for a large project with many scenes. There has to be a way for blender to do this in a "smarter" way.

Comment: This sounds like a job for the compositor. Color profiles are not the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to affect color globally, through a variable accessible in the color management controls, you need to create LUTs (Look Up Table), that will allow you to convert values of pixels in an image into other values. Creating LUTs has to be done in a different program, Blender has no tools for this. There are many Lut creation programs available online, DaVinci Resolve would work fine as well.

Once created, the LUT has to be saved into one of the folders where Blender stores the LUTs that constitute the color management system.

To make the LUT accessible in blender's color management, there is a file that needs to be updated with the information for the new LUT. The file is called config.OCIO. Create new definitions (or stanzas) in that file so that the new luts can be applied to the images. Creating new "looks" would work for your purposes.

For detailed instructions, please refer to the following posts:

[How to make 3D LUTs and use them in Blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65948/how-to-make-3d-luts-and-use-them-in-blender)

and

[Can I use my 3D Luts with Flimic?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/194306/can-i-use-my-3d-luts-with-flimic/194330#194330)

Note though that LUTs will not *self adjust* or *analize data* to convert values from scene to scene depending on varying brighness and ranges. LUTs  are static, in the sense that they will only work for a certain set of data and will not re-adjust to others. For a case-to-case conversion of parameters you would need some scripting and other kinds of trickery before you process information throught luts.

Comment: This sounds exactly like what I am looking for. Thank you, I will let you know if it works.