# Color Management - View Transform in Video Editor

Tags: video, lut

I have an XT4 and use F-Log for filming. I followed the links in [How to create a custom colour management profile](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/196640/how-to-create-a-custom-colour-management-profile) to add the Fuji LUTs from https://fujifilm-x.com/global/support/download/lut/ to the config.ocio. In the 'Compositing' tab, after adding an 'Input' - 'Movie Clip' node, I can set 'Look' (in 'Render Properties' - 'Color Management' - View Transform 'Filmic') to one of the Fuji LUTs and the effect is visible in a 'View' node and in render output. So the installation of the LUTs seems to have worked.

I want to use the same LUTs in the video editor. In a new scene I go to the 'Video Editing' tab and in the 'Sequencer' add a movie; I can't find a place where the LUTs can be applied. I can't see a 'Color Management' section in the sequencer. There is one in 'Properties' - 'Output Properties' - 'Output' next to the preview window, which defaults to 'Follow Scene' but even if I change that to 'Override' and select the XT4 LUTs it has no effect on the preview or the rendered output.

Alternatively, in the sequencer I try to import the original scene where I initially set the LUT in the compositor. I can see other color adjustments made in the original scene (e.g. made with a 'Color Balance' node) but the effect from the LUT is not visible in the video editor (of the new scene).

How can I apply the LUT to a video file so it's visible in the video editor?