# Can I save rendered images as PNG with a sRGB color profile?

Tags: color-management

It is my understanding that I can save rendered images at best as PNG files. But what about color profiles ?

The manual says:

> The other place to keep color management in mind is when loading and
>   saving image files. File formats such as PNG or JPEG will typically
>   store colors in a color space ready for display, not in a linear
>   space.
>
> When working with image files, the default color space is usually the
>   right one. If this is not the case, the color space of the image file
>   can be configured in the image settings.

[image]

Where can I find those settings ??? Where can I set the color space of images ? In [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28284/colour-shift-whe%E2%80%A6) it is said that

> Saving to a JPEG or TIFF at 8 bits per channel will apply a nonlinear
>   sRGB curve to the data, and may change the internal float format to
>   the respective format's storage type. Saving to an EXR will transfer
>   the internal reference space buffers unchanged which, by nature of
>   EXR, is a linearized float scene referred format.

What does this mean ?? Does this mean the image are saved in sRGB by default but no color profile is attached to the image ? So best to assign sRGB to the image when opened in Photoshop ?

Comment: This may help (If you haven't already read it)https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.64/Color_Management

Comment: Since my preference is GIMP, I don't know Photoshop. However, since I know Gimp has the capability to manipulate the color space, and format of an image, I would expect that Photoshop does, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a sizable degree of erroneous information listed here; some lacking clarity, while other bits could be classified as entirely misinformation or misleading.

> Where can I set the color space of images?

Complex question that requires a deeper understanding of colour management and in particular, how OpenColorIO is designed, but the short answer is from the UV Image Viewer's Properties panel.

> Does this mean the image are saved in sRGB by default but no color
>   profile is attached to the image ?

If you do nothing to the default configuration, yes.

> So best to assign sRGB to the image
>   when opened in Photoshop?

Yes.

> How is Blender saving the images ... with to without color profile?

Yes.

> And is that sRGB?

Complex question, but simple answer is “Yes.”

Comment: I know that I have to better understand color management for motion pictures but for now I am interested how I can (best) save my rendered images ? In PNG format I thought, but as far as I know I cannot chose or assign a color profile ? How is Blender saving the images ... with to without color profile ? And is that sRGB ?

Comment: Colour doesn't require profiles. Perhaps an instant message format works better here. Go to the chat forum that is cegaton's @JanScherders.http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34814/cegaton-and-whoever-wants-to-join

Comment: Ok. To summarise ... By default images are saved in sRGB, but Blender does not assign a color profile to the image. So when opened in Photoshop you best assign a sRGB color profile to the image.

Answer (score -3):

You can find the color management settings in the Scene pane.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: yes, I have seen the color management panel. but where can I make the settings for savings files (I mean the color profile) ?

Comment: This "Color Management" panel is where you change the settings. Render the image then under the "Image" tab select "Save As Image" from the drop down menu. The settings you made in color management will be applied.

Comment: OK. So when I have chosen sRGB for Display Device, then Blender will save the images as sRGB. Does Blender assign a sRGB color profile ?

Comment: The settings under RENDER. I'll mark up the posted photo.

Comment: you mean log/raw/default/film/rrt ? I know where to save the rendered image, but in in the manual it is said that you can set the color space of the image (see the png I included in my question) but I cannot find those settings in blender. Sorry

Comment: I'm not sure Jan. It might be version specific? You can set the color space in the panels I mentioned above. As well as exposure, gamma...

Comment: In my question I refer to the Blender Manual. The settings panel I show comes from the manual.

Comment: hi Dontwalk, I guess I have asked a bad question. Probably that is the reason for those down votes of your answer. Sorry